# RabbitMQ Vs. MSMQ for Microsoft Azure Cloud Platform

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, msmq, mom

I would like to use a Message-Oriented-Middleware (MOM) with Microsoft Azure cloud platform. 
I've done a little comparison between RabbitMQ and MSMQ. The first one seems to be better for my case. It is easier to work with and features as monitoring and managing need to be implemented in MSMQ unlike RabbitMQ.

But as MSMQ is a Microsoft product, I think it will be more compatible with Microsoft Azure cloud Platform than RabbitMQ.

Any link or advice will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure has a built in MOM Messaging Platform that is the official successor of MSMQ named Service Bus http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/messaging/

Comment: thanks, but Service Bus seems to be paying. I want to work with a free MOM. Any idea about making RabbitMQ or MSMQ work with Microsoft Azure cloud platform?

Comment: I think you could create (or use any existing) VM to install RabbitMQ and build virtual network to connect to other VMs in your solution. But you need to pay for your RabbitMQ VM, and some installation/configuration/maintenance effort as well. If you are using Service Bus, you do need to paybut you don't need to take care of it. I think this is the reason we select cloud computing.